# How can I import groovy class to build.gradle script?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have this project structure:

[image]

And I try to use these classes in `build.gradle` script:

`task generateStubs(type: XjcExecTask) {`

But Gradle doesn't see this class `XjcExecTask`.

I try to add `import com.pavel.*` to this script but it doesn't recognize.

Comment: maybe you need to use `buildSrc` to store your Groovy code that is expected to be used in your build script, see:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources

Answer (score 0):

If your custom Groovy classes `XjcExecTask` and `WsimportExecTask` purpose is to be used by your build script only (and not packaged into a library you will share to other projects), then you should move the `builder` subproject into a so-called `buildSrc` project:  see detailed description in following guides:

https://guides.gradle.org/writing-gradle-plugins/
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources